# I want to let my Discord Bot send images/gifs

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I've been trying every bit of code I find that might work but either the command doesn't load (it says the bot is typing and then stops) or just the bot itself doesn't work. I'm using Python.

Comment: Are there any errors? What have you tried? What exactly do you want to happen? See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: There aren't exactly any errors, the most that's happened was the bot would be typing for around 5-10 seconds and then stop. I've tried looking around seeing if I could use any code people have left around but it never works.. And what I want to happen is for the bot to respond to a command and attatch an image/gif to it. Something like https://gyazo.com/f5b7f19612994232e237d795eb1d222d

Comment: [Here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-upload-an-image)'s a link to an FAQ in the [`discord.py` documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). [Here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/584)'s another link to a post in the [`discord.py` GitHub repository](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/). Do either of these help?

Answer (score 52):

I know your problem is already solved, but I will post an answer so that people who have this same problem will be able to find the solution easily.

To send an image or GIF, here are two options (adapted from [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-upload-an-image)):

1. Opening the file and sending it directly to the channel:

   ```
   with open('my_image.png', 'rb') as f:
       picture = discord.File(f)
       await channel.send(file=picture)
   ```
2. Passing the file name directly:

   ```
   await channel.send(file=discord.File('my_image.png'))
   ```

Here are some useful links:

- [`discord.py` docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [Related `discord.py` FAQ](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-upload-an-image)
- [`discord.py` GitHub repository](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/)
- [Related `discord.py` GitHub post](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/584)

Comment: If you are modifying a bot that happens to be responding to messages, it is likely you want to use message.channel.send

Comment: What if the image comes from a URL and not the local machine?

Comment: How to reply to a user with a Image?

Comment: ensure that your bot also has the "Attach Files" permission

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, you can use URLs for images/gifs by adding the link as a standard message to be sent by your bot.

```
async def _cowgif(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send("http://imgur.com/gallery/YiMUiop")
```

Note that this is an asynchronous request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `file` parameter

```py
await ctx.send("Any text", file=discord.File("NAME.png"))
```

**If you get an error with file path:**

```py
import os

//Not necesarryif the fileis in the same folder!
os.chdir("C:/Users/COMPUTER-NAME/Desktop/Bot-Folder/") 


await ctx.send("ANY TEXT", file=discord.File("NAME-OF-THE-IMAGE.png"))
```

*If you use embed:*

```py
embed.set_image(url="DIRECT IMAGE URL")
```