# Is there a way to convert a folder of images (pngs, gifs) to an arraylist in Python?

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm creating a discord bot for fun as a hobby for some friends to have on our server!
I'm learning python programming as well as some extra stuff for the discord bot but I'm at a loss of how to convert a folder of images into an ArrayList so that I could randomly choose an image for a command that sends a gif or png as a response!

Comment: You can encode the images using `cv2.imencode()` into string and store them in an ArrayList and then send the string in the response and decode it using `cv2.imdecode()`

Comment: Which part are you struggling with, specifically? _`ArrayList`_ Isn't that a type of object in Java? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this to get the file paths:

```py
import os
imagePaths = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
# Assuming you have a directory of only .pngs and .gifs
```

And when you need to select one on random, the following could help

```py
import random

randomImagePath = random.choice(imagePaths)
```

For actually sending the image, you can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52241051/i-want-to-let-my-discord-bot-send-images-gifs). For consistency, I'll add what it looks like in total in a small test script:

```py
import os
import random
import discord

""" Any discord setup needed """

def imageGenerator():
    imagePaths = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
    while True:
        yield random.choice(imagePaths)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    gen = imageGenerator()
    with open(next(gen), 'rb') as f:
        picture = discord.File(f)
        await channel.send(channel, picture)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you response!

For the first part where you imported os, what does the "[f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]" represent?

Comment: Sure, `os.listdir` will list everything in the directory `"."`, which is your working directory. What `os.path.isfile` does is checks to see that they are actually files being added (`listdir` will also add any directories that it finds too, this filters so only files are in your list)

Comment: I see! So I'm looking at the test script where you defined the function imageGenerator. I use the method of `await ctx.send(file=discord.File( file name)` in to send the image. So, in theory, would I be able to call the imageGenerator function in place of the file name since it fields a random image?

Comment: You should use `next(gen)` for the file name. It is a generator, not a function. I could also implement a function implementation as well, but I felt a generator was more fit for your situation

Comment: I see! So in the if statement, what would the __Name__ and __main__ represent as variables as well as the 'rb'?

Comment: I would suggest searching stack overflow. In my opinion `__name__` and `__main__` are just syntatic sugar meaning "run this only if I am running this script specifically". `rb` means to read bytes, not just read. Please search stack overflow/python documentation, these are explained much better by others

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217387/discussion-between-m-z-and-kurooyukii).

Answer (score -2):

```
import random
import glob

image_paths = glob.glob("Plate_examples/*.jpg") #load all the jpg file from this directory
img = []
for images in image_paths: #loop through the list of image path
    img.append(images)   # append each image path into this list 
    
randomImagePath = random.choice(img) # select each path at random
```

Comment: Aren't `img` and `image_paths` identical? What's the purpose of duplicating the variable.