# discord.py Invalid Form Body In embed.image.url: Scheme "<discord.file.file object at 0x000001e151c02360>" is not supported

Tags: python, discord.py

i tried it

```
data_stream = io.BytesIO()
    data_stream.seek(0)

    l = ['Communication', 'dress', 'food', 'culture', 'other']
    plt.pie(r, labels=l, autopct='%.1f%%')
    plt.savefig(str(ctx.author))
    chart = discord.File(data_stream, filename=f"{str(ctx.author)}.png")
    
    embed = discord.Embed(title = 'ㅁㄴㅇㄹ', description = 'ㅁㄴㅇㄹd')
    embed.set_image(url=chart)
    plt.close()
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

but  error ..

**Invalid Form Body
In embed.image.url: Scheme "<discord.file.file object at 0x000001e151c02360>" is not supported. Scheme must be
one of ('http', 'https').**

how i can fix this bug?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to let my discord bot send images/gifs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52241051/i-want-to-let-my-discord-bot-send-images-gifs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is in the error, you are trying to set image with a File but a url is expected.

There is a way to transform your image into an url which is explained in the Discord.py [FAQ](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html) (important to read!).

I think that the [How do I use a local image file for an embed image?](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-use-a-local-image-file-for-an-embed-image) question corresponds to yours.

Have a nice day!