# How can I send a picture with the Discord API and Python Requests

Tags: python, image, python-requests, discord

It's my first time posting here, and I want to ask you if you can help me to find a way to send a picture in a channel with the **Discord API with Python Requests**. (I'm not talking here about discord.py or Discord Bots).

To write the code, I first checked in the Network Tab and upload a picture to see what request it's actually sending.
In the form data, I can see that it's sending two informations:

```
file: (binary)
payload_json: {"content": "", "tts": false}
```

The last thing who is needed is to send our Discord Token in the header

When I tried to write the code, the response they gave me is

```
{"message": "Cannot send an empty message", "code": 50006}
```

Even if I add a text in the content, they give me the same error.
I guess I didn't put the right information in the data.

Here's the code:

```
import requests

# User's Token
header = {
    'authorization': "token",
}

# Data
payload = {
    "file" : open("picture.jpg", "rb").read(), # The picture that we want to send in binary
    "payload_json": {"content":"","tts":False},
}

channel_id = "829628868860051480" # Channel where we send the picture

r = requests.post(f"https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{channel_id}/messages", data=payload, headers=header).text
print(r)
```

Comment: `I'm not talking here about discord.py or Discord Bots` Why can't you just use discord.py, your making your life extremely hard trying to manually send data using requests. With discord.py [it is a single line of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52241051/i-want-to-let-my-discord-bot-send-images-gifs) `with open('my_image.png', 'rb') as f: channel.send(file=discord.File(f))`

Comment: @user9321739 it sounds like they want to send a message on a user account. This is against [Discord's ToS](https://discord.com/terms). (I may be wrong but they did say "I'm not talking here about discord.py or **Discord Bots**")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to isopach, I figured out what to write, I post it here in case someone need to do the same thing as me

```
import requests

# User's Token
header = {
    'authorization': "token",
}

# File
files = {
    "file" : ("./picture.jpg", open("./picture.jpg", 'rb')) # The picture that we want to send in binary
}

# Optional message to send with the picture
payload = {
    "content":"message"
}

channel_id = "channel_id" # Channel where we send the picture

r = requests.post(f"https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{channel_id}/messages", data=payload, headers=header, files=files)
```

Comment: It's just showing up as a generic file that you can download, not an image. And even if you click on it to save it it still doesn't open

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to send the file as a `multipart/form-data` according to the [docs](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file).

Put them in a tuple nested in a dict.

```
files = {
    'file': ('./picture.jpg', open('./picture.jpg', 'rb')),
    
}

r = requests.post(f"https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{channel_id}/messages", data=payload, headers=header, files=files).text
```