# How to add images with Discord API and Python Requests

Tags: python, python-requests, discord, bots

I want to send an image that I have stored on my computer through this code

```
import requests
import time
headers = {'authorization': TOKEN, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

url = f"https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{CHANNEL}/messages"
        data = { "content": message }
        files = {
            'file': (open('image.png', 'rb')),
        }
        r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data, files=files)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            print(f"sent message to {CHANNEL} {r}")
        else:
            print(f"error while sending to {CHANNEL} {r}")
```

But I ended up getting this error.

```
error while sending to CHANNELID <Response [400]>
```

I don't quite understand what the problem is, as it should work.

I tried to use embed or attachment, but it got same error.

Comment: Could you print error message from the response `r.text`?

Comment: error while sending to 1087008158460944414 {"code": 50109, "message": "The request body contains invalid JSON."}

Comment: I searched for same error, here is same as mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68499998/how-can-i-send-a-picture-with-the-discord-api-and-python-requests . But it's still don't work

Comment: The error indicates that there is something wrong with json. What's the format of your `message`?

Comment: Format of my message is string

```message = '''My MSG
ALSO MY MSG'''
```

Comment: also problem isn't with message. If i remove files it starts working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When uploading files, Discord API expects that the `Content-Type` is set to `multipart/form-data`. If you want to let Discord automatically discover the `Content-Type`, you can omit this header in your request. I have tested the code below.

```
import requests
import time
headers = {'authorization': TOKEN}

url = f"https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{CHANNEL}/messages"
data = { "content": message }
files = {
    'file': (open('image.png', 'rb')),
}
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data, files=files)
if r.status_code == 200:
    print(f"sent message to {CHANNEL} {r}")
else:
    print(f"error while sending to {CHANNEL} {r}")
```