# I'm trying to send an image using a discord bot but its only sending the file name

Tags: python, discord

I'm trying to pull the image randomly out of a folder, yet it only show the image name.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

if message.content.startswith('$Monke'):
    arr = os.listdir('C:/Users/cmalc/Documents/Word/School shit/Coding/Thonny Files/Discord Bot/Monke Pictures')
    await message.channel.send(random.choice(arr))
```

I've changed the bottom code to

```
if message.content.startswith('$Monke'):
    await message.channel.send(file=discord.File(random.choice('C:/Use...
```

Comment: Because `listdir` returns a list of string - filenames. See the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52241051/i-want-to-let-my-discord-bot-send-images-gifs)

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych. Ive changed the code. now im getting FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'd'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`random.choice` returns one element from the given iterable which now is a string, so it returns a random character. `random.choice(arr)` is the right one to use here. But don't forget to add the path to a file name:

```
if message.content.startswith('$Monke'):
    random_file = os.path.join('C:/Users/cmalc/Documents/Word/School shit/Coding/Thonny Files/Discord Bot/Monke Pictures',
                               random.choice(arr))
    await message.channel.send(file=discord.File(random_file)
```