# How do I send an image using discord.py

Tags: python

what I'm trying to do is first get the message of a user, draw it onto an image, and then send it

everything works, **except** the part where its supposed to send the image, so how do I do that?

```
from msilib.schema import File
from tkinter import font
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont
import discord


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    username = str(message.author).split('#')[0]
    user_message = str(message.content)
    channel = str(message.channel.name)
    print(f'{username}: {user_message}({channel})')

    if username == "ChrisMightShootYou":
        font = ImageFont.truetype(font='D:\DOWNLOAD\DiscordBot\FuturaBookFont.ttf', size=84)
        image = Image.open('D:\DOWNLOAD\DiscordBot\erdemoji.png')
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im=image)
        draw.text(xy=(340, 50), text=user_message, font=font, fill='white', anchor='mm',stroke_width=4,stroke_fill='black')
        image.show()
        async def send(message):
            await client.send_message(client.get_channel(), File=discord.File(image))
```

Comment: Look into message attachements

Answer (score 0):

You can read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52241776/18728017).

You must open the file in `rb` (read binary) mode. and then use discord.File to send it.

But in this class, we have a `if` !

```
if isinstance(fp, io.IOBase):
    if not (fp.seekable() and fp.readable()):
        raise ValueError(f'File buffer {fp!r} must be seekable and readable')
    self.fp = fp
    self._original_pos = fp.tell()
    self._owner = False
else:
    self.fp = open(fp, 'rb')
    self._original_pos = 0
    self._owner = True
```

If you enter the file path, this will be done automatically.

So you just need to give the file path to discord.File :)

```
await channel.send(file=discord.File('path\to\photo'))
```