# Random file selection doesn't work (Discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm using Github so no OS here.

I'm trying to make it so you can write the command /mila and it will get you a random photo from my Github repository.

```
import random

@bot.command()
async def mila(ctx):
        Images = ["photo_2022-09-29_16-56-28.jpg", "photo_2022-09-29_16-56-31.jpg", "photo_2022-09-29_16-56-33.jpg", "photo_2022-09-29_16-56-35.jpg", "photo_2022-09-29_16-56-37.jpg", "photo_2022-09-29_16-56-38.jpg", "photo_2022-09-29_16-56-41.jpg", "photo_2022-09-29_16-56-42.jpg", "photo_2022-09-29_16-56-45.jpg", "photo_2022-09-29_16-56-47.jpg"]

        await ctx.send(random.choice(file=Discord.File(Images)))
```

Comment: in your code you are trying to make a file from a list `Discord.File(Images)` and then passing that as an arg to the random choice function `random.choice(file=Discord.File(Images))` (in fact as keyword arg `file` which doesn't exist).  Instead you should first choose a random file and then make a Discord.File from that `file = Discord.File(random.choice(Images))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to let my Discord Bot send images/gifs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52241051/i-want-to-let-my-discord-bot-send-images-gifs)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This should work,

```
import random

@bot.command()
async def mila(ctx):
        Images = ["photo_2022-09-29_16-56-28.jpg", "photo_2022-09-29_16-56-31.jpg", "photo_2022-09-29_16-56-33.jpg", "photo_2022-09-29_16-56-35.jpg", "photo_2022-09-29_16-56-37.jpg", "photo_2022-09-29_16-56-38.jpg", "photo_2022-09-29_16-56-41.jpg", "photo_2022-09-29_16-56-42.jpg", "photo_2022-09-29_16-56-45.jpg", "photo_2022-09-29_16-56-47.jpg"]
        
        random_file = random.choice(Images)
        await ctx.send(file=Discord.File(random_file))
```

Comment: it worked, but you gotta do `discord` with lower caps ;D

Comment: Yeah i just slightly edited it so u can figure out the rest